# Real time reporting software

Tags: real-time, reporting, business-intelligence, dashboard

I have this problem and was wondering if anyone can help. I have a number of data feeds (CSV files, web APIs) that I would like to report on but can't find anything open source or paid that can do the job. Basically I want to be able to attach any data feed to this system and build a simple report (select fields, couple of aggregations) which are then distributed to my team. The system could either be a desktop app or web based, don't mind. Each member of my team would have different levels of access to this and the report would present the data in tabular formats, charts and pivots. I looked at Tableau and Qlikview but they are not ideal for real time reporting.

Any ideas if there is anything like that out there?

Comment: Take a look to http://www.seektable.com/

Comment: Thanks I will have a look

Comment: How real time you want it to be?, real real time, or updated every X amount of time?

Comment: For some teams real real time is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Altough not a reporting tool , theres an charting api called highcharts which has components for real time reporting, the only problem is that you will have to code everything.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look

Answer (score 1):

Power BI has the option of creating link, and then the data get refreshed automatically. If you import it then it's not real time.

Comment: I tried Power BI but its not the kinda of real time app I am after. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use signalR. Here is the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr